# DryIoc Container Exception only in RELEASE mode for XF w/ Prism Android App

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, prism, dryioc

I am getting the following exception, but only in the RELEASE build for a `Xamarin.Forms` Android app built with `Prism` w/ `DryIoc` container and the Popups Plugin (which the exception is referring to). The app runs fine in DEBUG. I am only using SDK assembly linking.

Has anyone run into this?

Any suggestions for determining root cause/fixing?

I get this exception when running in Release mode only and I have no idea why - can someone please help me with this? Works perfectly in Debug mode.

The exception gets thrown when attempting to do the first navigation (using INavigationService.NavigateAsync).

> DryIoc.ContainerException: 'Unable to resolve
>   MyProject.ViewModels.LoginPageViewModel with passed arguments
>   [value(Prism.Plugin.Popups.PopupPageNavigationService)]
>   IsResolutionCall from Container without Scope with Rules with
>   {AutoConcreteTypeResolution} and without
>   {UseFastExpressionCompilerIfPlatformSupported} with
>   Made={FactoryMethod=ConstructorWithResolvableArguments} Where no
>   service registrations found and no dynamic registrations found in 0 of
>   Rules.DynamicServiceProviders and nothing found in 1 of
>   Rules.UnknownServiceResolvers'

I'm using:

> Visual Studio Enterprise version 16.2.5 on Windows 10
>   Xamarin Forms version 4.2.0.778463
>   Prism.DryIoc.Forms version 7.2.0.1367
>   Prism.Plugin.Popups version 7.2.0.573
>   Rg.Plugins.Popup version 1.1.5.188

Here are my release csproj settings, which I modified to let me debug it on my physical device:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants> <!-- get rid of debug -->
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidLinkMode>SdkOnly</AndroidLinkMode>
    <AndroidSupportedAbis>armeabi-v7a;</AndroidSupportedAbis>
    <AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>true</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>
    <AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler</AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>
    <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>true</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
    <BundleAssemblies>false</BundleAssemblies>
    <AotAssemblies>false</AotAssemblies>
    <EnableLLVM>false</EnableLLVM>
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>false</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
    <AndroidEnableProfiledAot>false</AndroidEnableProfiledAot>
    <AndroidEnableMultiDex>false</AndroidEnableMultiDex>
    <JavaMaximumHeapSize>1G</JavaMaximumHeapSize>
    <AndroidEnableSGenConcurrent>true</AndroidEnableSGenConcurrent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Here's the registration in **App.xaml.cs**, and I have decorated the App class with Prism's [AutoRegisterForNavigation]. I Tried to explicitly register PopupNavigationService and Popups (the first 2 commented out lines) but it didn't make a difference.

```
    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        // Services / Plugins
        //containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IPopupNavigation>(PopupNavigation.Instance);
        //containerRegistry.Register<Prism.Plugin.Popups.PopupPageNavigationService>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterPopupNavigationService();
        containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IContactService>(CrossContactService.Current);
        containerRegistry.Register<IDialogService, DialogService>();
        containerRegistry.Register<IQuoteProviderService, QuoteProviderService>();
        containerRegistry.Register<IMessageCheshirerService, MessageCheshirerService>();
        containerRegistry.Register<IMessageTrackerService, MessageTrackerService>();
        containerRegistry.Register<IEmailService, SendGridEmailService>();


        containerRegistry.Register<IAnalyticsService, FakeAnalyticsService>();
        containerRegistry.Register<IAuthenticationService, FakeAuthService>(); // note this overrides the real platform-specific implementations as desired
        containerRegistry.Register<IApiManager, FakeApiManager>();
        containerRegistry.Register<IInAppPurchaser, FakeInAppPurchaser>();

        containerRegistry.Register(typeof(IApiService<>), typeof(ApiService<>));

        // Non-Auto-Registered Views
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
    }
```

Comment: I think we will need your App.xaml.cs: where your declare your navigation and your dependencies.

Comment: I hope you have called below line of code....protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    // This updates INavigationService and registers PopupNavigation.Instance
    containerRegistry.RegisterPopupNavigationService();
}

Comment: ^ yes, that is why the app works perfectly fine in debug mode, @Roubachof I have updated to include my App.xaml.cs, so this line can be seen there, as well as my RELEASE settings for the android app (which I have modified to allow me to debug it). Thank you for taking a look.

Answer (score 1):

This error message was a red herring for a completely different, nested dependency that was not properly registered for the release mode build.... please disregard.